# How do I add a member function as e.g. Boost Log filter?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I want to add a member function as a logging filter via:

```
boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::phoenix::bind(&LoggerContext::checkIfShouldBeLogged, this, <WHICH_ARGUMENT_DO_I_PASS?>));
```

where the signature of the filtering function is

```
bool LoggerContext::checkIfShouldBeLogged(const boost::log::attribute_value_set &attributeValueSet);
```

just as described in the documentation.

I do not know which argument to pass from the function I am trying to add the filter in.

If I make that function static, I can simply omit the argument and set the filter like so:

```
boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(&LoggerContext::checkIfShouldBeLogged);
```

The argument seems to be passed magically.

Same goes for setting a custom formatter. The following works for a static function:

```
sink->set_formatter(&LoggerContext::fileFormatter);
```

with the signature

```
void LoggerContext::fileFormatter(boost::log::record_view const &rec, boost::log::formatting_ostream &strm);
```

But I again do not know where to get the arguments from in order to pass them, when using `boost::phoenix::bind`.

Comment: Not familiar with boost phoenix but for `boost::bind` you will need to pass a placeholder object to leave that argument exposed to the caller: `set_filter(boost::phoenix::bind(&LoggerContext::checkIfShouldBeLogged, this, _1));`. Otherwise you can simply try using a lambda: `set_filter([this](auto &attrValueSet) { return checkIfShouldBeLogged(attrValueSet); })`.

Comment: Reading section _Record placeholder_ of [Lambda expressions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html)  I found out how to pass a member function as a formatter

`#include <boost/log/expressions/record.hpp>
sink->set_formatter(boost::phoenix::bind(&LoggerContext::fileFormatter, this, expressions::record, expressions::stream));`

but still no idea on how to access `boost::log::attribute_value_set`?

Answer (score 0):

@Jorge Bellon: I just now read you comment, it gave me a good hint as to how this works.

The solution is to use the `boost::phoenix` placeholder. This works for both the formatter and the filter:

```
boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::phoenix::bind(&LoggerContext::checkIfShouldBeLogged, this, boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1));

sink->set_formatter(boost::phoenix::bind(&LoggerContext::fileFormatter, this, boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1, boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg2));
```

Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Happy to help! Have you tried using a C++11 lambda? It's way more readable.

Comment: I do not use lambdas a lot as I am not a fan of the concept. But sure, next time I must use them I'll have a look at the C++11 lambdas.